# When sending a UDP packet to a client, the server is receive the packet it just sent instead?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I'm using UDP for client/server communication, I have the client send a packet which the server receives and then the server sends a packet response, but when the server sends the response the server is the one receiving the response, not the client.

I have a Server object running in one process, and a Client object being ran in another process and is connecting to localhost. Both the client and the server inherit from AbstractHost. AbstractHost has a Sender and a Receiver object. The Receiver has a thread that sits on receive (blocking) until a packet comes in, when a packet comes in it passes the packet data to the Client/Server's "onReceive" function. It's causing an infinite loop in the Server where the Server sends a packet and then the Server receives the packet (it shouldn't) which causes it to send another packet etc...

As far as I can tell it's because im doing it on the same computer, but for testing purposes I need this to be able to work.

Code: http://pastebin.com/raw/jhX98Jhp
Using pastebin because stackoverflows code formatting never works for me

Comment: Just to clarify, because I had an issue following at first. The client sends a packet to the server. The server then sends a response packet, but instead of sending it to the client it sends it to itself.

Comment: *"Using pastebin because stackoverflows code formatting never works for me"* - It works for other people.  You just need to learn how to use it.  Hint: get rid of TAB characters.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently UDP Client will not send the packet over the defined port, so grabbing the port from the received packet and using that to respond fixed it.